# Brew doctor error config

Tags: macos, config, homebrew

When I use the `brew doctor` command on Mac OS X Lion, I get the following error:

> Error: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
>   `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
>   software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
>   compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
>   Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
>   script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
>
> /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/passenger-config

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. I'm seeing the same warning from homebrew, and would like to know how serious it is, and if there is known workaround.

Comment: I have the same problem and could not find any solution. This happens only when someone uses ruby. Is it not programming related?

Comment: @BM5k My guess: because it's a [su] or [apple.se] question. Besides the error message seems pretty clear on how to resolve the problem: get `…/passenger-config` out of `$PATH`, or ignore it if you're certain it's not overriding anything "built-in".

Comment: Passenger is a server commonly used in the Rails community. The answer to this question is far more likely to be known by the StackOverflow audience.

Comment: Yet another useful question that is closed. Moderators, have you considered suggesting edits or moving the question to a more appropriate stack exchange site instead?